# Proguard error android, unable to access jar file

Tags: android, proguard

This is the first time I am using progurad and getting the following error on exporting signed apk.

> Error: Unable to access jarfile ..\lib\proguard.jar

I uncommented the proguard.config= line

```
   # To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available   properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
   proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

But there still seems to be some issue.
What is needed to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a known bug in ADT 22.6 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66733

Fortunately, working around [that bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66733) is easy. On Windows, simply edit proguard.bat and provide an absolute path to the proguard.jar file.

Comment: Can you please tell me a step by step procedure to do that?

Comment: Edit the file proguard.bat that you will find in your ADT installation path, ie: d:\adt\sdk\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat . This file has a line "SET PROGUARD_HOME=..", change it to the full path where your proguard directory is, ie: "SET PROGUARD_HOME=d:\adt\sdk\tools\proguard"

Comment: Hi! How to handle the same problem on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug happens when you update from an older version of eclipse.  A better fix is this:

Find the PROGUARD_HOME environment variable in the Windows system settings.  Change it to the proguard directory, e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse-helios\sdk\tools\proguard
```

Then, exit and restart eclipse so will read the new setting.