# How do I encrypt or hide my api url in android?

Tags: android, api, security, encryption

I am working on a client server application in which I have an API from my server which sends me response in JSON.

If somehow anyone tries to extract my code from the apk. I do not want to let him know my API.
What are the steps should I use to encrypt it?
Any specific way or some encrypt algo.

How do I hide this api in my code:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Database ? any rooted device can read DB and even many app available to change DB run time from phone

Comment: @raj for inserting link in database you should have that link in your code then how can it would be encrypted?

Comment: Follow the Below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816825/how-to-hide-api-url-and-parameters-in-android-app/47942035#47942035 It works!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your link in string.xml file
example-

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MYAPP</string>
    <string name="myurl">http://www.google.com</string>

</resources>
```

& access it in activity as

```
  getString(R.string.myurl);
```

it's working at my side.

Comment: using tool i can read XML files and String extractor tools available

Comment: @milaptank Please can you share how string.xml file can be extracted while encrypting apk file for my knowledge

Comment: using apkanalyser tool you can extract all your XML file of apk even layout XML also :)

Comment: I just change apk extention to .zip I can see all the resources

Comment: still u can see by decompiling it

Comment: the url will be displayed  when you decomplied apk

Answer (score 0):

use function

```
public String getUrl()
{
    String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    return url;
}
```

if you have any argument than pass that arg in function arg
 if you have multiple urls than you can use switch case

```
    // switch (URL_type) {
    // case BASE_URL:
    // return baseUrl = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
    // break;
    //
    // default:
    // break;
    // }
```

any tool that decompile java file than its only show function name not function code

**Use proguard-project to protect your APK**  see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Comment: I tired using proguard and got this error. Can you solve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498111/proguard-error-android-unable-to-access-jar-file/22646688?noredirect=1#22646688

Comment: see this links http://viralpatel.net/blogs/protect-java-code-decompilation-using-java-obfuscator/                     https://java.net/projects/shield4j/pages/Home

Comment: milapTank have you tried this ? are you sure ? it will work ?

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi once i have tried decompile at that time i am not able to retrieve function code but still i am in search of String encrypt

Comment: Hey @HammadTariqSahi i found this `https://gist.github.com/milaptank/25de743c6417a3ccb4da9ca35748fbcc` . Is it help us ??