# Retrofit2: Is it possible to hide API url defined as static inside class?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm new to Android programing. I'm using `retrofit2` to create an API. I'm now wondering if there is a way to hide API url defined  as a static variable inside class.
I'd like to store the url inside `string` folder if possible. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you can use proguard to ensure not  finding url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think the best way to do this in code level is to:
  - encrypt the variable url and decrypt it when you will use on retrofit instead of putting it on a res / raw file or string folder or xml.

- don't add httploggingInterceptor on retrofit when building a production apk
- always use pro guard on retrofit

Comment: Hi I just want to hide url so other people cannot see this when I upload the project somewhere. Could you make what you are saying more clear?

Comment: You still can but not a good practice , try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942035

Comment: So you want to upload your project somewhere (for example, Github), but you don't want anyone to see your API base url?

Comment: @Rhen Thanks for good resource. I think this way can solve my problem

Comment: can show me example